# Getting “408 Request Timeout”

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, mule, mule-studio

while invoking an API in UAT via postman, we are frequently getting HTTP 408 timeout error. First time we always get this error after which it works fine. Below is the screen shot of splunk logs. we have configured it through Mulesoft.

[image]

please help me understand the issue. why at thefirst time it always gives HTTP408 and then it works fine and then again in between it gives the same response HTTP408.

API - Web API 2.0 .NET

Comment: the image looks a bit blurry, could you include those messages as text with proper formatting ?

Comment: Can you provide more info? What is the request you send? Do you manage the API or is it an external provider? A 408 means: "A server SHOULD send the "close" connection option1 in the response, since 408 implies that the server has decided to close the connection rather than continue waiting. If the client has an outstanding request in transit, the client MAY repeat that request on a new connection." https://httpstatuses.com/408 Maybe your request is to heavy?

Comment: You didn't provide any details of the requests nor the API implementation. Are you implementing the API with Mule? Which version of Mule and connectors used? Share the flows involved. Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: @Max I am not the sender, we own the API and the client faces this issue. we have provided them the endpoints, headers etc. They have configured it in Mulesoft and calling it from there. we are not able to see this time out failed responses in any of our api logs. looks like its not reaching to the server. not sure if they are messing up something while calling or what ? we alrdy did the load testing n dint face any timeout error.